# Microsoft Access 2007 & VBA & CSV and ...stuff

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access-2007, ms-access

I have an assignment for work purpose which isn't really hard to do but I'm not a proficient access user so I, hereby, come to you guys :)

I'm about to write VBA code that is actually a custom CSV files loader. It's going to parse some files and insert their content in the appropriate tables.
My question is: What is the most appropriate way of creating this loader and triggering it?
I guess I have to create a VBA Module in my database project, but then what are the possiblities for the user to invoke the script and load the files ?
Like... is there any file system browser control that I can pop open and ask the user to choose a csv file then load it or whatever else ?

Thank you for your hints guys

Miloud B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user's point of view, it is probably easiest for you to create a form (or a series of forms) to take them through the import process.  You can then attach your VBA code to those forms.

You can use the FileDialog to let the users select a file.  It's the same dialog box that comes up when you want to open a file in any other Windows program.  Microsoft explains how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243865(office.12).aspx).  It's not the clearest explanation, but if you Google "Access FileDialog" or "Access OpenFileDialog" you can find more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim/acLinkDelim`

Comment: Thank you I will do that immediately

Answer (score 1):

For the user the easiest will be to use right click on tables, import, select the data, choose the place to import to.

Comment: The import process has to collect data from csv files with a *weird* organization so I have to do this myself. In fact, I'll maybe ask them if they could be satisfied with that way of working. Thank you